# MapReduce not reducing?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm following the tutorial at http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html and this is my code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class WordCount {
    public static class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private Text word = new Text();
        private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text val, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = val.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line.toLowerCase());
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            while (value.hasNext()) {
                IntWritable val = (IntWritable) value.next();
                sum += val.get();
            }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(config, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new     Path("/user/Icarus/words.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/user/Icarus/words.out"));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

But when I run it instead of calculating the word frequency, I got this:

```
bye 1
goodbye 1
hadoop  1
hadoop  1
hello   1
hello   1
hello   1
world   1
```

I must missed something very trivial but I can't figure out what. Help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of this problem is, You are not calling the `reduce()` with the exact `Signature` required to call by `Hadoop`. Signature should be as below (reference [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#reduce(KEYIN,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context)))

```
protected void reduce(KEYIN key, Iterable<VALUEIN> values, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
               throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

Since your `reduce()` not matching the `Signature`, `Hadoop` will call default [**IdentityReducer**](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityReducer.html), which output the same input.
So only you are getting the same output of Map as Reduce output.

For this problem, i can suggest you 2 solutions,
**First**:  Try the below code

```
public static class WordCountReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
```

**Second**: And second solution is quite simple,
Instead of you define manually reduce class, Just set the Reducer class to `IntSumReducer` or `LongSumReducer` which will do the same as above code.
So don't define the `WordCountReducer` class and add the following code,

```
job.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class); or  
job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
```

based on the count type you want.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your first code works, but why.. seems the only difference is how we consumed the iterator.

Comment: You should be using `Iterable` instead of `Iterator` to work your code and use for loop to iterate it